# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.util.JsonWriter on API 8?

Tags: android, openmobster

My code works fine on API 11 and higher but crashes on API 8.
When I looked into log, Issue is I am using JsonWriter which is added in API 11.
I am developing my android application to work on API 8 and higer, is there away to use the JSONreader/JsonWriter in API 8?

log :

```
    07-29 11:20:26.815: E/dalvikvm(305): Could not find class 'android.util.JsonWriter',    referenced from method org.openmobster.core.mobileCloud.android.storage.Record.toJson
    07-29 11:20:26.815: W/dalvikvm(305): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 893    (Landroid/util/JsonWriter;) in Lorg/openmobster/core/mobileCloud/android/storage/Record;
    07-29 11:20:26.823: D/dalvikvm(305): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0008
    07-29 11:20:26.823: D/dalvikvm(305): VFY: dead code 0x000a-0064 in  Lorg/openmobster/core/mobileCloud/android/storage/Record;.toJson ()Ljava/lang/String;
    07-29 11:20:26.893: W/dalvikvm(305): threadid=9: thread exiting with uncaught  exception (group=0x4001d800)
    07-29 11:20:26.933: E/AndroidRuntime(305): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-10
    07-29 11:20:26.933: E/AndroidRuntime(305): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:  android.util.JsonWriter
    07-29 11:20:26.933: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at  org.openmobster.core.mobileCloud.android.storage.Record.toJson(Record.java:164)
    07-29 11:20:26.933: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at  org.openmobster.core.mobileCloud.android.storage.DefaultCRUD.addRecord(DefaultCRUD.java:583)
    07-29 11:20:26.933: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at org.openmobster.core.mobileCloud.android.storage.DefaultCRUD.insert(DefaultCRUD.java:74)
    07-29 11:20:26.933: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at org.openmobster.core.mobileCloud.android.storage.Database.insert(Database.java:132)
    07-29 11:20:26.933: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at org.openmobster.core.mobileCloud.android.errors.ErrorHandler.save(ErrorHandler.java:139)
    07-29 11:20:26.933: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at org.openmobster.core.mobileCloud.android.errors.ErrorHandler.handle(ErrorHandler.java:77)
    07-29 11:20:26.933: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at org.openmobster.android.api.rpc.MobileService.sendRequest(MobileService.java:152)
    07-29 11:20:26.933: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at org.openmobster.android.api.rpc.MobileService.invoke(MobileService.java:57)
    07-29 11:20:26.933: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at org.openmobster.core.mobileCloud.android.kernel.DeviceContainer$1.run(DeviceContainer.java:3 14)
    07-29 11:20:26.933: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at  java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
    07-29 11:20:28.564: I/dalvikvm(305): Could not find method  android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams.<init>, referenced from method  android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuView$LayoutParams.<init>
```

Answer (score 1):

> is there away to use the JSONreader/JsonWriter in API 8?

No. You will need to switch to something else, whether that be the `org.json` classes (in the Android SDK) or a third-party JSON library (e.g., Jackson, GSON).

Answer (score 0):

Error is NoClassDefFoundException it means compiler unable to find your class

so you need to mention this class perfectly as per my undestanding you are using library for this project if yes then follow below step to resolve error of "NoClassDefFoundException"

1 ) Right click on project

2) goto properties

3) goto java build path

4) goto order and export tab

5) check in library which you include for your project

6) click ok apply the changes and compile your code

hope it will work for you

Comment: "My code works fine on API 11 and higher but crashes on API 8." If the missing jar were the actual problem, it won't work on API 11 neither.

Comment: i am not sure may be u need android.jar to support lower version may b m wrong but try it hope it will help u :)